# What am I doing wrong while parsing this XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an xml that has the following structure
[image: Structure]

And here's the code snippet Ive written to parse it

```
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println ("Root element: " +
                    doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());//prints GoodReadsResponse correctly
        NodeList bk = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");// single all encompassing element in response

        Node n= bk.item(1);// since the 0th node is id the 1st must be the title
        System.out.println("Node value"+n.getLocalName());
        Element e=(Element)n;
        NodeList titleList= e.getElementsByTagName("title");//get the title
        Element titleElem = (Element) titleList.item(1);
        Node titleNode = titleElem.getChildNodes().item(0);// get the node value
        book.setTitle(titleNode.getLocalName());// this prints null instead of printing Hamlet--why??
        System.out.println("Title in parser"+titleNode.getLocalName());//null again
```

EDIT: The problem as pointed out in code is that `titleNode.getLocalName()` is always null and Im not being able to figure out why. Ive placed my thought structure as comments in the code.
Any idea why this is happening? Pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: it will be better if you post xml text instead of image. If someone wants to try your code, the xml is also required, image is not helping.

Comment: Problem statement is in his code comments.. couple of values are NULL.

Comment: @JunedAhsan: I understand. But I would have to disclose my API credentials if I provided the URL to the page. Hence the image.

Comment: Is your aim to print title '`Hamlet` ?

Comment: I'm guessing `getLocalName()` isn't even supposed to do what you think it's meant to do. The text in a text node should be the node *value.

Comment: Personally my answer would be: use JDOM. The standard Java DOM is simply aggressively dumb. (Mostly because the W3C DOM is, on accounts of being a specification that goes for accurately in representing the infoset over programmer convenience.

Comment: @millimoose You were right. Its `getNodeValue()` that was playing the prank

Comment: You can also use 'getTextContent` on `title` element.

Answer (score 1):

The following code

```
NodeList bk = doc.getElementsByTagName("book"); //This get All BOOKS
```

returns a NodeList of all items of books, since you have only one book in your xml you should follow this with

```
Node n= bk.item(0);
```

In this case n = book node
Also you will have to do the same for Title to be like this

```
NodeList titleList= e.getElementsByTagName("title");//get All titles
Element titleElem = (Element) titleList.item(0);
```

And then the rest of your code should work fine!

Comment: Yes there was an issue with the index. But cant accept your answer because the primary error was in `getNodeValue()`

Comment: Probably have to add this line to cast `Node` n to `Element` to make it work.   `NodeList titleList= ((Element)n).getElementsByTagName("title");//get All titles`

Comment: @KodeSeeker that's alright as long as you already solved it :)